# php hide variable from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this PHP and javascript code below. I'm wondering if its possible to hide the variable $sp_key from the html source? I want to make it private or hidden so that no one can know that key. is that possible?

```
<?php 

$sp_key = "1OowsHMmw6o0AFnJB8SkDzeJP3erziZ6_Nzgxgz1DxZ4";

?>

<script>

        // the KEY  is still visible in the html source code. how to hide?
        var sp_id = '<?php echo $sp_key; ?>';
        //


</script>
```

I tried PHP with ajax but still no luck from below:

PHP code:

```
<?php
// filename: keysp.php
    $advert = array(
        'ajax' => 'Hello world!',
        'advert' => $row['adverts'],
     );
      echo json_encode($advert);
?>
```

Javascript Code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'keysp.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : "test",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {
       alert(result['ajax']); // "Hello world!" alerted
       console.log(result['advert']) // The value of your php $row['adverts'] will be displayed
    },
    error : function () {
       alert("error");
    }
})
```

The problem is in my file keysp.php <-- when i view this page, the json data is still visible. so anyone can still see my key.

Is still anyway I can hide the key?

Comment: Put it in external js file

Comment: request the key at runtime

Comment: Everything you send to client will be seen. So - __do not send__ this data to client.

Comment: Why do you set the value at served HTML if the value is expected to be hidden from client?

Comment: An external js file is still going to be visible. If your JS needs the value, there's no way to stop the user from finding it. Alternatives depend on what you're doing with that key.

Comment: use hide or display none in js

Comment: @sarancheln How will that solution affect the source code?

Comment: what do you want exactly

Comment: Don't emit key for javascript. Instead store key only in server and fetch it with Ajax from some server URL. Also obfuscate this URL in client side and decode it with javascript

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I did. I updated my post but the key is still visible in json. any ideas how to hide it completely?

Comment: 1. Don't use direct URL 'keysp.php' in ajax. Instead use obfuscated / encrypted link and decode it in javascript, assign to variable then and pass this variable into ajax call URL parameter. 2. Same applies to JSON data. You can encrypt keys for JSON at server-side, and decrypt them in client-side with Javascript. Of course still human with developer skills can reverse-engineer your JS code and extract real keys. Your only bet is to make this harder by obfuscating your Javascript code. But no 100% security exists in any case